# Rent increase under Scotland's temporary rent cap

Tags: united-kingdom, residential-lease, rent, scotland

I have a private residential tenancy (PRT) agreement and have been renting my apartment for over 12 months.  Under a PRT, a landlord can increase the rent [no more than once a year](https://www.gov.scot/publications/about-rent-service-scotland/) and must give a tenant at least three months' notice of any increase.

Recently, my landlord sent me a letter outlining a 50% rent increase from May 2024 onwards (three months from now).  I'm not sure if this is legal.

Scotland has a temporary rent cap in place:

- The landlord cannot increase the rent by [more than 3% until at least 31 March 2024](https://www.mygov.scot/rent-cap-landlords/when-you-can-increase-the-rent). The landlord can apply to Rent Service Scotland to increase the rent for the lower of: 50% of the increased costs, or 6% of the existing rent.
- If Rent Service Scotland agree that the landlord can increase the rent, they will [let the landlord and myself know](https://www.mygov.scot/rent-cap-landlords/when-you-can-increase-the-rent).  Should I receive a letter or email from Rent Service Scotland?
- According to the [Scottish Landlords Association](https://scottishlandlords.com/news-and-campaigns/news/rent-increases-after-31-march-2024/),  rent increase notices issued before 1 April are still subject to a 3% cap, even if the increase doesn't come into force until after that date.  Not sure if this true.

What are my legal options?

Comment: 1. Your question risks being closed for asking for legal advice. Try rephrasing more generally / as a hypothetical. 2. Contact Shelter Scotland if you have not already done so. https://scotland.shelter.org.uk/